# The best locator in Ruby cucumber for image (class)

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I started learn Ruby (cucumber).  In one project (from Internet), I have:

```
class HomePage
  include PageObject

  page_url FigNewton.baseurl

  #divs(:name, class: 'name') #sprawdzanie diva na stronie
  #buttons(:view_detail, value: 'View Details')

  def select_puppy(name = 'Brook')
    view_detail_elements[index_for(name)].click
  end

  private

  def index_for(name)
    name_elements.find_index { |div| div.text == name }
  end
end
```

---

instead of this:

```
 #divs(:name, class: 'name') #sprawdzanie diva na stronie
 #buttons(:view_detail, value: 'View Details')
```

I want to give something for my img (attachment)
How can I do this? Which solution is the best?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqXm8.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "give something for my img"? Are you asking about creating an accessor for img elements, similar to what `divs(:name, class: 'name')` does?

Answer (score 0):

```
image(:logo, :class=> 'main-logo hidden-xs hidden-sm')
```

or

```
link(:title, :href=>'/')
image(:logo){title_element.image_element}
```

Ofcourse, if the link returns multiple elements you will have to modify the locator.